# How do we do hierarchical includes with local paths?

Tags: include

I need to generate an appendix with hundreds of tables.  I put several tables on a page, as an earlier question established.  The first level consists of pure tables, created as `\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}` blocks.  Let's call 4 such primitive files `ch1-{a,b,c,d}.tex`, i.e. `ch1-a.tex`,`ch1-b.tex`, ...  These four documents are emitted into a directory `/tex/ch1/`.

The second level, which I call `2x2-ch1-abcd.tex`, is also a tabular, containing

`\include{a}`

-- it is generated in the same subdirectory, `/tex/ch1/`.  So far so good.  If I wrap `2x2-ch1-abcd.tex` in a preamble, it compiles.

Now I need to assemble such level 2 aggregates into a thesis.  I have the master document as `/tex/thesis.tex`.  If I say, in it,

`\include{ch1/2x2-ch1-abcd}`

-- I get the no nested includes error.  If I replace `\include` by `\input`, the second level cannot find the first level files anymore.

I'd like to avoid encoding first-level paths into second-level matrices, to keep paths only in the master document.  Can it be achieved within LaTeX without external symlinks?

Answer (score 3):

I believe (untested) that you can solve the problem with the import package:

```
\usepackage{import}
...
\subimport{ch1/}{ch1-a.tex}
   ...
   \input{2x2-ch1-abcd}
```

(where indentation denotes inclusion within the file above in the heirarchy). If you wish to `\include` the chapter file (rather than `\input`) it, use `\subincludefrom` instead of `\subimport`.

Comment: Thanks Will -- I decided to simply generate proper paths for each \input, but this is a very interesting path and yielded many more things on hierarchy, such as TEXINPUTS, security policy, etc.