# \importonly for only processing a single import?

Tags: include, import

I am composing a large document, and instead of using include/input, I use the `\subimport*` command from the `import` package. This allows me to take care of relatives paths very easily.

However, the nice thing with `\include` is that I can use `\includeonly` to only include certain files, without breaking references. Is there a similar command for `\subimport`?

### edit

I'm trying to put together some code that would do fix this, but my LaTeX knowledge is really very limited. I wrote some kind of weird pseudocode-like thing, may be of help?

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\origsubimport\subimport
  \newcommand\subimportonly[1]{\let\somevar=#1}
  \renewcommand\subimport[1]{\@ifstar
                             if #1 == letvar, use origsubimport*; 
                             o/w just include aux?
   }}
\makeatother
```

Comment: `\includeonly` works fine. You need to use `\subincludefrom` variante.

Answer (score 2):

Update all instances of `\subimport` to `\subincludefrom`, and remove the '.tex' extension from the path.

For example, this use of `\subimport`:

```
\begin{document}
\subimport{intro/}{intro.tex}
\subimport{chap1/}{chap1.tex}
\subimport{discussion/}{discussion.tex}
\end{document}
```

Would become this:

```
\begin{document}
\subincludefrom{intro/}{intro}
\subincludefrom{chap1/}{chap1}
\subincludefrom{discussion/}{discussion}
\end{document}
```

After you have compiled at least once, and you now only want the discussion (for example) included, you can add an `\includeonly` to the preamble, like so:

```
\includeonly{discussion}
\begin{document}
\subincludefrom{intro/}{intro}
\subincludefrom{chap1/}{chap1}
\subincludefrom{discussion/}{discussion}
\end{document}
```

And the document will only include discussion.tex. This makes the edit-compile-view loop faster by not including sections you aren't working on, but uses the *.aux files for the intro.tex and chap1.tex includes to prevent any references from breaking.

Thanks to @touhami's comment, [this answer to Speed up compilation by (pre-)compiling chapters separately?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1991/30485) and [this answer to How do we do hierarchical includes with local paths?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10217/30485) for helping me join the dots.

Answer (score 2):

As of time of writing, the [existing answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351411/120853) does not work on either `Debian/TeXLive 2019 (LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5), import 6.0` or `Windows/MiKTeX 2.9 (LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3), import 6.1`. Both are fully updated.

Just two days ago, 2020-04-01, version `6.2` was released and is [available on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/import). Using that `sty` file manually, the issue was not fixed.

Meanwhile, I had to issue (borrowing @Paul-Calcraft 's example)

```latex
\includeonly{discussion/discussion}
\begin{document}
\subincludefrom{intro/}{intro}
\subincludefrom{chap1/}{chap1}
\subincludefrom{discussion/}{discussion}
\end{document}
```

That is, with the full path in `includeonly`.
Otherwise, there is a very unexpected `warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.` greeting, since all document content is inside of `subincludefrom` commands.